# How to create an interaction between charts in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, interaction, sankey-diagram

I want to make two charts interactive. The code for the charts can be found in the following links: https://github.com/irbp005/d3SankeyAndLineInteraction

The visual representation of the charts is as follows:

[image: Sankey and Line Chart visualization]

The lines represent the trend value of the node A, B & C.

What I want to do is that when hovering over the A, B & C nodes the corresponding lines in the line chart get highlighted and vice versa, when hovering over the lines in the line chart the nodes in the sankey chart get highlighted.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this interaction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some quick modifications to achieve your aims:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SANKEY Static Sankey Visualization</title>
<style>
 .node rect {
   cursor: move;
   fill-opacity: .9;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
 .node text {
   pointer-events: none;
   text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
 }
 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-opacity: .2;
 }
 .link:hover {
   stroke-opacity: .5;
 }
 .axis path,
 .axis line{
   fill: none;
   stroke: black;
 }
 
 #A{
   fill: none;
   stroke: rgb(15, 58, 88);
   stroke-width: 5px;
 }
 
 #B{
   fill: none;
   stroke: rgb(85, 97, 113);
   stroke-width: 5px;
 }
 
 #C{
   fill: none;
   stroke: rgb(124, 62, 6);
   stroke-width: 5px;
 }
 .tick text{
   font-size: 12px;
 }
 .tick line{
   opacity: 0.2;
 }
</style>
<body>

<p id="chartSankey"></p>
<p id="chartLine"></p>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/d3/d3-plugins/master/sankey/sankey.js"></script>

<script> 
// ## Datasets for Sankey visualization
var graph = 
 {
 "nodes":[
 {"node":0,"name":"A"},
 {"node":1,"name":"B"},
 {"node":2,"name":"C"},
 {"node":3,"name":"D"},
 {"node":4,"name":"E"},
 {"node":4,"name":"F"}
 ],
 "links":[
 {"source":0,"target":3,"value":200},
 {"source":0,"target":4,"value":300},
 {"source":0,"target":5,"value":500},
 {"source":1,"target":3,"value":400},
 {"source":1,"target":4,"value":600},
 {"source":1,"target":5,"value":1000},
 {"source":2,"target":3,"value":600},
 {"source":2,"target":4,"value":900},
 {"source":2,"target":5,"value":1500}
 ]};
// ## Datasets for linechart 
var dataset = [
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 1, y: 28},
  {x: 2, y: 131},
  {x: 3, y: 152},
  {x: 4, y: 187},
  {x: 5, y: 245},
  {x: 6, y: 345},
  {x: 7, y: 481},
  {x: 8, y: 559},
  {x: 9, y: 632},
  {x: 10, y: 820},
  {x: 11, y: 800},
  {x: 12, y: 1000}
];
var dataset2 = [
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 1, y: 74},
  {x: 2, y: 174},
  {x: 3, y: 393},
  {x: 4, y: 593},
  {x: 5, y: 814},
  {x: 6, y: 1038},
  {x: 7, y: 1276},
  {x: 8, y: 1529},
  {x: 9, y: 1756},
  {x: 10, y: 1860},
  {x: 11, y: 1900},
  {x: 12, y: 2000}
];
var dataset3 = [
  {x: 0, y: 0},
  {x: 1, y: 95},
  {x: 2, y: 295},
  {x: 3, y: 406},
  {x: 4, y: 518},
  {x: 5, y: 869},
  {x: 6, y: 1282},
  {x: 7, y: 1403},
  {x: 8, y: 1504},
  {x: 9, y: 1840},
  {x: 10, y: 2050},
  {x: 11, y: 2500},
  {x: 12, y: 3000}
];
 
</script>

<script>
// ## Original source for Sankey https://gist.github.com/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13
// ## Option to move nodes eliminated
// ## Order of nodes disabled on sankey.js (//nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);) to maintain the order of data, which is alphabetical and prevent for the nodes to be ordered by size 
// ## Codigo inicial adquirido para el Sankey https://gist.github.com/d3noob/c2637e28b79fb3bfea13
// ## La posibilidad de mover los nodos se ha eliminado
// ## La ordenacion en el archivo sankey.js se ha desbilitado (//nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);) para mantener el ordenen de los datos y evitar que los nodos se ordenen por tama~o 
var units = "$";
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 40, left: 20},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),    // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " " + units; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();
// append the svg canvas to the page
var svg = d3.select("#chartSankey").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// Set the sankey diagram properties
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(40)
    .size([width, height]);
var path = sankey.link();
  sankey
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .layout(32);
// add in the links
  var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d){
         return "link " + d.source.name;
      })
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; })
      .on("mouseover", function(d){
        var s = d.source.name;
        d3.selectAll(".line").style('opacity', .1);
        d3.select("#" + s).style('opacity',  1);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.selectAll(".line").style('opacity', 1);
      });
      
      
      
// add the link titles
  link.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.source.name + " → " + 
                d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
// add in the nodes
  var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
// add the rectangles for the nodes
  node.append("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
      .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { 
    return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        var s = d.name;
        d3.selectAll(".line").style('opacity', .1);
        d3.select("#" + s).style('opacity',  1);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d){
        d3.selectAll(".line").style('opacity', 1);
      });
    
    node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { 
    return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
// add in the title for the nodes
  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", null)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
      .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
      .attr("text-anchor", "start");
   
</script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset3, function(d){ return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset3, function(d){ return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickSize(-height);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
 .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);
 
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });
 
var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });
var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });
 
var svg = d3.select("#chartLine").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("id", "A")
      .on("mouseover", highlight)
      .on("mouseout", function(){ d3.selectAll(".link").style('opacity', 1);   });
  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset2])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("id", "B")
      .on("mouseover", highlight)
      .on("mouseout", function(){ d3.selectAll(".link").style('opacity', 1);   });
  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset3])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("id", "C")
      .on("mouseover", highlight)
      .on("mouseout", function(){ d3.selectAll(".link").style('opacity', 1);   });
      
  function highlight(){
    var id = this.id;
    d3.selectAll(".link").style('opacity', 0.1);
    d3.selectAll("." + id).style('opacity', 1);
  }
   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mark, this is really great, great, great. Thanks!!