# Make lines between 2 charts

Tags: d3.js, chart.js

My question is more conceptual than technical. I want to make 2 graphs related to each other with lines connecting important points of each graph. Something like the image below, where the vertical dotted lines connect the triangle wave tothe red bars below:

[image: a chart with a triangle wave on top and colored bars on the bottom]

So before I get into it I would like to know if it is possible to do it using D3js or any similar library.

The idea of doing it on the web is to be able to interact with it. As in this example ->[`Interactive chart`](https://jsfiddle.net/robinovitch61/3nwjzkdx/)

The closest thing I've found, interacting with 2 graphs, is this ([2 chart with related interaction, but no between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533259/how-to-create-an-interaction-between-charts-in-d3)) but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.